# Drag and paste like excel using jquery?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, copy-paste

I want to create a dynamic table that content can be modifiable. I want to add a feature like excel where I could drag and drop a `<TD>` data that paste in all other `<TDs>`.

Comment: I want to apply handsontable.js feature on my existing table but it's too complicated. any suggestion @charlietfl ??

Comment: what does too complicated mean? The docs and examples are pretty good

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is Drag Events?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop